# MySQL : select/join on strings as fieldnames - is this possible?

Tags: mysql, select, join

I can retrieve all column names from table 'categories' with :

```
SELECT col.column_name
FROM information_schema.columns AS col
WHERE col.table_schema= database() and col.table_name = "categories"
```

This produces a resultset like this :

```
column_name       
-----------------
categoryID
name
description
```

I can retrieve all values for a specific category with :

```
SELECT * 
FROM categories AS c 
WHERE c.categoryID=12345
```

this results in a resultset like this:

```
categoryID      | name     | description
------------------------------------------------
12345           | test     | this is a test
```

Now I would like to get some kind of join of above selects to get a resultset that looks something like this :

```
fieldname         | value
----------------------------------------
categoryID        | 12345
name              | test
description       | this is a test
```

Does anyone know if this is possible ?  Can you do a join on strings that come from another select ??

The reason for this is that I'm writing a universal stored procedure that outputs all fields + their values from a table, without knowing what fields there are in the table.  (The tablename is given in a parameter)

Comment: is that bad? :)  Still have to find out how this works...

Comment: It works by clicking the check mark when someone answers your question. Surely if you can use mysql, you can click a  check mark.

Comment: not happy with the answer? spend some efforts to include reason into your question

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to select a field value using a dynamic field name. This can't be done using a simple SQL and even using a stored procedure you would still have to take the lines one by one using PREPARE STATEMENT.

If you are using the console and want to see the results of you query nicely displayed try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM categories AS c 
WHERE c.categoryID=12345 \G
```